# Sort by a column in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
Table "items" that contains a list of items with a "rare" column.
Table "stash" that contains item_id and user_id.
I would like to get all items possessed by user_id 1 for example, and sort it by the item's "rare" (the rarest item will show first).
"rare" goes from 0 (not rare) to 3 (very rare).
How can I get the right query for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Read about joins in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select s.* 
from items i 
join stash s on (i.id = s.item_id) 
where s.user_id = 1 
order by i.rare
```